# Apply subset function to a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I have a list of `SpatialPolygonDataFrame` that I can assimilate to `dataframe` like this:

```
df.1 <- data.frame(A = c(1:10), B = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 5:10))
df.2 <- data.frame(A = c(1:10), B = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7:10))
df.3 <- data.frame(A = c(1:10), B = c(1, 2, 2, 4:10))

list.df <- list(df.1, df.2, df.3)
```

I would like to get a list of a subset of each dataframe based on condition (`list.df.sub` is the result I am looking for):

```
df.1.sub <- subset(df.1, df.1$B != 2)
df.2.sub <- subset(df.2, df.2$B != 2)
df.3.sub <- subset(df.3, df.3$B != 2)

list.df.sub <- list(df.1.sub, df.2.sub, df.3.sub)
```

I would like to apply directly my subset on `list.df`. I know that I have to use `lapply` function but don't know how?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should work:

```
lapply(list.df, function(x)x[x$B!=2,])
```

or with `subset`:

```
lapply(list.df, subset, B!=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to subset one column, you can also use the "[[" function

```
example_list <- list(iris, iris, iris)
lapply(example_list, "[[", "Species")
```